# Get subarray of byte

Tags: c#, arrays

In C#, How I can get sub array of bytes like this

`byte[] arrByte1 = {11,22,33,44,55,66}`

I need reference for sub array of two bytes like 33 and 44 values.

I found multiple options are there like Array.Copy, ArraySegment, LINQ (Skip and Take) in C#. what is best solution for that from performance point of view?

Comment: What is the source of these bytes? And how big is the array? You may find Stream classes useful..

Comment: "what is best solution for that from performance point of view" - do you really think that this is going to be the bottleneck in performance for your application? The best way to achieve good performance is to set performance *goals*. Then, set those goals aside and just write simple, clear, understandable code. Then, *measure* the performance. If it meets the goals, job done, and move onto the next task. If it *doesn't* meet the goals, isolate *where* the performance bottleneck is. It's unlikely to be here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Easy perfomance test:

```
public void Test()
{
    const int MAX = 1000000;

    byte[] arrByte1 = { 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66 };
    byte[] arrByte2 = new byte[2];
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    // Array.Copy
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        Array.Copy(arrByte1, 2, arrByte2, 0, 2);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Array.Copy: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    // Linq
    sw.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        arrByte2 = arrByte1.Skip(2).Take(2).ToArray();
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Linq: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Result:

```
Array.Copy: 28ms
Linq: 189ms
```

Perfomance test on large data:

```
public void Test()
{
    const int MAX = 1000000;

    int[] arrByte1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).ToArray();
    int[] arrByte2 = new int[500];
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    // Array.Copy
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        Array.Copy(arrByte1, 500, arrByte2, 0, 500);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Array.Copy: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    // Linq
    sw.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        arrByte2 = arrByte1.Skip(500).Take(500).ToArray();
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Linq: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Result:

```
Array.Copy: 186ms
Linq: 12666ms
```

*As you see, on large data linq have troubles.*

Comment: We should do `sw.Restart()` for the Linq test, otherwise the `sw.ElapsedMilliseconds` also includes the `Array.Copy()` milliseconds.

Comment: Added `Buffer.Copy()` test here: https://gist.github.com/fraguada/301fe31b939e6889514969cb1bbec37c

Answer (score 10):

[Buffer.BlockCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) is faster than Array.Copy for byte arrays.

Comment: For the test posted by @General-Doomer, `Buffer.BlockCopy()` is indeed faster. I've added a gist with a test for `Buffer.BlockCopy()` and  `ArraySegment<int>().ToArray()`: https://gist.github.com/fraguada/301fe31b939e6889514969cb1bbec37c

Answer (score 7):

Use [Array.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy#overloads).

Example:

```
int[] target = new int[2];
Array.Copy(arrByte1, 2, target, 0, 2);
```

Format:

```
Array.Copy(source, source index, target, target index, length);
```